# Code review for Listing all firebase users as a promise

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

This isnt so much a question more code review on what I have written.

I had a go at converting the firebase list all users code into a promise function. I wanted retrieve an array of all users in one go, rather than using the function callbacks.

Could anyone tell me whether this could break, either from using too much memory or some other problem.

I will leave the user batch param as 1 to show that the async does seem to work.

```
const userArray = [];

// list all users
const listAllUsers = function (nextPageToken){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    admin
      .auth()
      .listUsers(1, nextPageToken)
      .then(async(listUsersResult) => {
        listUsersResult.users.forEach((userRecord) => {
          console.log('user', userRecord.email);
          userArray.push(userRecord.email);
        });
        if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
          console.log("There is a next page token")
          await listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
          resolve();
        } else {
          resolve();
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error listing users:', error);
      });
  });
};

// Start listing users from the beginning, 1000 at a time.
await listAllUsers();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... the code will use an amount of memory that is at least linear to the number of users. So if you have no limit on the number of users, you will also have no way to predict the amount of memory it needs.

The question that immediately jumps out at me is why you would need a list of all users? What are you going to do on that entire list, that you can't do on a single page of users?

Comment: I was hoping to save all user ids to a text file.. I figured it would be easier to list them and put them all in an array and then just write that to a text file

Comment: @ebg11 "I was hoping to save all user ids to a text file.." => If this is to do a kind of backup from time to time, have a look at the `auth-export` [CLI command](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#auth-export)

Comment: Ok so the root of this was to do with disabling billing. I dislike the idea of receiving a large bill for hobby projects so looked at disabling billing using the pubsub triggers.  I am a little concerned that on this page https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify it talks about permanently deleting resources. I was hoping I could store the email addresses before I disable billing to ensure I still have a method of contacting users (i could send the file via slack). Do either of you to know whether disabling billing will delete firebase auth email/password user records?

Comment: "Do either of you to know whether disabling billing will delete firebase auth email/password user records" => AFAIK changing from Blaze plan to Spark plan will not delete any users in Firebase Auth. Note that apart from Phone Auth, the Auth service is free.

Comment: I have managed to get a version working using the firebase tools node module and auth-export as you suggested, seems to work well. Although it may not be needed Im gonna leave it in as a precaution. Thankyou both of you for the help :)